# How to refresh / reload focused tabs of tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am trying to make my tabbed activity content to change dynamically, depended on the user choices in the other tabs.

**All tabs are using the same fragment**. only the content in the view is supposed to change (in this case a ListView)

Now the main problem is that when I make a choice (click on some line in the ListView) the next tab shows all of the content instead of filtering the data according to my choice in the previous tab, though when I click on a not-neighbor tab and then go back, the tab is filtered like I wanted.

From what I understand, the activity load the neighbor tabs of the current tab even if those are not focused and this is why I get the default result.

To simplify things:

Then I choose some line from the ListView and the focus automatically goes to the next tab.

The listView will show me the default contet, as if I chose nothing. But if I move the focus to the forth tab, and then again back to the second, the listView will be filtered as I wanted

Here is my code

```
public class Catalog_actbartabs extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_actbartabs);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

}


public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog_actbartabs, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    protected ClogListAdapter2 clogListAdapter2;
    protected ArrayList<String[]> stringArrayList;
    protected static String topic = null;
    protected static String rName = null;
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private static final String EXTRA_ITEM_INFO = "com.dstudio.dvir.EXTRA_ITEM_INFO";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalog, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));


        try {
            if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1)
                stringArrayList = Utils.getNamesList(super.getContext());
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2)
                stringArrayList = Utils.getTopicsList(super.getContext(), rName);
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3)
                stringArrayList = Utils.getClassesList(super.getContext(), rName, topic);
            else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4)
                stringArrayList = Utils.getFilesList(super.getContext());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(super.getContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String[] values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("myKey");
            if (values != null) {
                stringArrayList = ClogListAdapter2.bmListFromArray(values);
            }
        } else if (stringArrayList == null) {
            stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        }

        clogListAdapter2 = new ClogListAdapter2(super.getContext(), stringArrayList, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        ListView listV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listV.setAdapter(clogListAdapter2);
        listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               
                if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                    if (clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0].equals("All"))
                        rName = null;
                    else rName = clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0];
                    topic = null;
                } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                    if (clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0].equals("All"))
                        topic = null;
                    else topic = clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0];
                } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), AudioPlayerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_INFO, clogListAdapter2.getItem(position));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }

                ((Catalog_actbartabs) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER), true);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "page 1";
            case 1:
                return "page 2";
            case 2:
                return "page 3";
            case 3:
                return "page 4";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

---

## UPDATE

### Working Solution From @AmeyShirke

I added the var `_hasLoadedOnce= false;` to the rest of the vars in `PlaceholderFragment` class:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    protected ClogListAdapter2 clogListAdapter2;
    protected ArrayList<String[]> stringArrayList;
    protected View rootView;
    protected static String topic = null;
    protected static String rName = null;
    private boolean _hasLoadedOnce= false;
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Now All the data setting code is inside `setUserVisibleHint()` without changing `_hasLoadedOnce` so it look like this:

```
        @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible_) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
            if (isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) {

                Log.i("visable: ", getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)+"");
                try {
                    if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1)
                        stringArrayList = Utils.getNamesList(super.getContext());
                    else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2)
                        stringArrayList = Utils.getTopicsList(super.getContext(), rName);
                    else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3)
                        stringArrayList = Utils.getClassesList(super.getContext(), rName, topic);
                    else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4)
                        stringArrayList = Utils.getFilesList(super.getContext());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(super.getContext(), "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                clogListAdapter2 = new ClogListAdapter2(super.getContext(), stringArrayList, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
                ListView listV = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listV.setAdapter(clogListAdapter2);
                listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO: 23/12/2016 remember to also give the needed info to get the asked next category
                        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
                            if (clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0].equals("All"))
                                rName = null;
                            else rName = clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0];
                            topic = null;
                        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
                            if (clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0].equals("All"))
                                topic = null;
                            else topic = clogListAdapter2.getItem(position)[0];
                        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), AudioPlayerActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_INFO, clogListAdapter2.getItem(position));
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                        }

                        ((Catalog_actbartabs) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER), true);
                    }
                });
                //Notify that _hasLoadedOnce = true; is now gone
            }
        }
    }
```

I also added the line `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` in the activity's `onCreate()` because if I chose to go directly to the forth tab after the first filtering it wouldn't filter it, so that way the activity will filter it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default behaviour of `ViewPager`. To load only single tab use:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

If that doesnt work, then you have to create your own sub-class of ViewPager and override the below method:

```
private boolean _hasLoadedOnce= false; // your boolean field

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isFragmentVisible_) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(true);


    if (this.isVisible()) {
        // we check that the fragment is becoming visible
        if (isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) {
            //your code here
            _hasLoadedOnce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this line and added it right after the mViewPager.setAdaper method but nothing has changed

Comment: I was able to override the method inside the PlaceholderFragment class. Sould I add something to this method? I still don't get the idea of how to implement the sub-class you'v talked about. And also, what is this `NetCheck().execute();` method? Is it related to what I'm trying to do? Because Android Studio is not able recognize `NetCheck`

Comment: `NetCheck().execute(); ` is just my sample..you should put your code instead of that i.e in place of (//your code here) do your data loading there. For more info, put a debug point on `if (isFragmentVisible_ && !_hasLoadedOnce) ` and see when it gets called and how many times. You will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried putting the code from the **try catch** statment in the `onCreateView` to the overriden func. At first it worked only for the second tab, but when I debugged the code I saw that the condition didn't work because the `_hasLoadedOnce ` was already `true` so I removed it and now it works fine.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)